# How do I uniquely identify cgcontext?

Tags: cocoa, macos, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

Is there any way by which it is possible to uniquely identify CGContextRef?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "uniquely identify"?

Comment: I am looking for some kind of identifier for CGContextRef which can help distinguish between two different context.

Comment: Robs answer seems to be what you're looking for. You could accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `CGContextRef` is just a pointer to a `CGContext` struct. Because it's a pointer you can just use equality to check if they're the same context:

```
if( context1 == context2 )
{
    //the contexts are the same
}
```

If you need to keep track of particular contexts, just store a reference to them, in an ivar or other variable. You can then use equality to check if a context matches:

```
if( someContext == yourContextIvar )
{
    //the contexts are the same
}
```

Comment: I am already using the reference technique. I was actually looking for some kind of API for this. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It needs no API for this since it's basic C stuff.